# How to write truncate query in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, prepared-statement, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm facing some issue in writing the truncate query in wordpress.
Here is my code

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'my_table';
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "TRUNCATE TABLE {$table_name}"), ARRAY_A );
```

The issue here is when I write query without prepare it shows a phpcs issue

```
Use placeholders and $wpdb->prepare();
```

And when I'm using the prepare function it shows the error

```
wpdb::prepare was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. The query argument of wpdb::prepare() must have a placeholder.
```

I don't have any placeholder here, what should I put here.
Any suggestions ??
Thanks

Comment: Do you need your query to be in "pure sql" format? Or you could use "WP_Query" too?

Comment: @Ruvee WP_Query will also work as long as it doesn't showing any error in wpcs